# Print operators

Tags: c, operators

I need help solving this problem in my mind so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

The task is: What the next code prints:

```
union uni { char s[2], c; } u={"A"};
printf("01:%d\n", sizeof(u));
printf("02:%d\n", sizeof(u.s));
printf("03:%d\n", sizeof(u.c));
printf("04:%x\n", u.c);
printf(u.s[1] ? "05:%c":"05:%d", u.c);
```

I don't understand why the print looks like this:

```
01:2
02:2
03:1
04:41
05:65
```

In the first print function, my opinion on why it prints 2 is because we have  two data of type char in the union.

In the second function it prints 2 because we have two elements of the array of type char.

In the third function it prints 1 because we have one data of type char.

In the fourth function, it prints 41, because 'A' is entered in the char data in the union, and 41 is the hexadecimal value of A.

I do not understand the fifth function for printing at all, because the condition of the ternary operator is unclear to me.

Can anyone explain to me why the printout is like this?

Comment: What **specifically** don't you understand?  How did the output differ from what you expected?

Comment: Note that to print the result of `sizeof()`, you should use the `%zu` format.

Comment: In the first print function, my opinion on why it prints 2 is because we have two charm-type data in the union.In the second function it prints 2 because we have two elements of the array of type char.In the third function it prints 1 because we have one data of type char.
In the fourth function, it prints 41, because 'A' is entered in the char data in the union, and 41 is the hexadecimal value of A.

Comment: The way you phrase your question it cannot be clearly decided whether what you want us to do is to write an answer for a homework or test or are actually asking for an explanation of something specific you do not understand or expect otherwise. People here tend to ignore "Do my homework" questions. So you better strengthen the aspect of wanting an explanation. You can do that by explaining all which you do understand and to state what for the other parts you would have expected instead of the shown output. That would focus your question on an answerable detail question.

Comment: My opinion on why it prints like this is stated in the comment

Comment: What is a _"two charm-type"_ ??

Comment: two data of type char

Comment: I want an explanation so I can see if I'm right, I also don't understand the printout for the fifth function, so I'd like someone to explain this to me to be sure.

Comment: So your question is "Why is the fifth printout like it is?". That is much more focused. Do you understand which part of the two options is used? Do you understand that there are two options, one of which is chosen? Do you know why? Do you understant how the chosen option has that output? In short, you need to go into more detail of what you do not understand...

Comment: *I do not understand the fifth function for printing at all, because the condition of the ternary operator is unclear to me.*  What will be the value of `u.s[1]`?  Is it equal to 0 (false), or not equal to 0 (true)?

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
union uni { char s[2], c; } u={"A"};
```

A variable named `u` is defined, of a union type declared in the same line.
The variable is also initialised with the value "A", which is a null-terminated sequence of 2 `char`s. The initialisation targets the first of the union options, an array of `char` with two elements. The array receives the `'A'` in index 0 and the `'\0'` in index 1.

Here

```
u.s[1] ? "05:%c":"05:%d"
```

The ternary operator is used to check the index 1 of the array (which contains the null terminator; boolean false). The option selected by the ternary is hence `"05:%d"`, i.e. a format specifier for an integer interpretation. Which is used to output the second union option. The output is hence the integer value, 65, by default in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

> `printf("01:%d\n", sizeof(u));`
> 01:2

`u` is a `union` type containing two members: a 2-element `char[]` array named `s`, and a single `char` named `c`.  All members of a `union` overlap in memory, so the size of the `union` is the size of its largest member, which in this case is `s`.  And since `sizeof(char)` is 1, the size of `s` is `sizeof(char) * 2 = 2`, thus the size of the `union` is 2.

> `printf("02:%d\n", sizeof(u.s));`
> 02:2

`s` is a `char[2]` array, so its size is `sizeof(char) * 2 = 2`.

> `printf("03:%d\n", sizeof(u.c));`
> 03:1

`c` is a single `char`, so its size is `sizeof(char) = 1`.

> `printf("04:%x\n", u.c);`
> 04:41

You are initializing `u` with the string literal `"A"`. Initializing a `union` initializes its 1st member (unless a designated initializer is used, which you are not doing).  Thus, `u.s` is initialized with `{'A', '\0'}`.  And because `u` is a `union`, `u.c` overlaps the 1st array element of `u.s` in memory, so `u.c` now contains the character `'A'`, which has an ASCII decimal value of 65. You are telling `printf()` to print the value of `u.c` as a hexadecimal integer, and the hexadecimal value of 65 is 0x41.

> `printf(u.s[1] ? "05:%c":"05:%d", u.c);`
> 05:65

The [`?:` conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) evaluates its 2nd operand only if its 1st operand is non-zero, otherwise it evaluates its 3rd operand.  In this case, you are essentially doing the *equivalent* of this:

```
const char* fmt;
if (u.s[1] != 0)
    fmt = "05:%c";
else
    fmt = "05:%d";
printf(fmt, u.c);
```

As stated further above, `u.s[1]` is initialized with the character `'\0'`, which has a numeric ASCII value of 0.  Since the 1st operand of `?:` is 0, the 3rd operand is evaluated, which is `"05:%d"`.  Thus, you are telling `printf()` to print the value of `u.c` as a decimal integer, not as a character.  And as stated further above, `u.c` contains the character `'A'`, which has a decimal value of 65.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a `union` can store only one of its members at a time, so only enough space is set aside for the largest member - in this case, that's the member `s` which is a 2-element array of `char`.

So the object `u` must be at least as large as `u.s`, which is a 2-element array of `char`; hence, `sizeof u == sizeof u.s == 2`.

The member `u.c` has type `char`, so `sizeof u.c == 1`.

Comment: It seems you missed the most recent explanations of what OP wants....

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
printf(u.s[1] ? "05:%c":"05:%d", u.c);
```

has the same behaviour as this:

```
if (u.s[1])  // shorthand for `if (u.s[1] != 0)`
  printf("05:%c", u.c);
else
  printf("05:%d", u.c);
```

Now it should be clear. Read about the ternary operator in your learning material.

Comment: I know this but where A is entered in s [0] ?

Comment: @LogicnotFound here: `union uni { char s[2], c; } u={"A"};`. Did you spot the `"A"`?

Comment: You mean you do not see where in the shown code the "A" is coming from? Did you search for "A"? It seems pretty obvious.

Comment: Why then is u.c also A?

Comment: @LogicnotFound you've understood why this is printed `04:41`, so I assumed that was clear. From your question: _"In the fourth function, it prints 41, because 'A' is entered in the char data in the union, and 41 is the hexadecimal value of A."_

Comment: @LogicnotFound because of the properties of `union`s. Look it up in your learning material.

Comment: Yes but when A is entered in c, in the first line or in the fourth?

Comment: @LogicnotFound the `A` comes only from `union uni { char s[2], c; } u={"A"};`. Nothing is modified in the other lines. You are aware the `0x41` is the same thing a `65` which is the same thing as `'A'`.

Comment: @LogicnotFound "*Why then is u.c also A?*" - because `u` is a **union**, so `u.s[0]` and `u.c` share the same memory. `u.s` is initialized to `{'A', '\0'}`, so `u.s[0]` is `'A'`, and thus `u.c` is also `'A'`.